# Adding a filter to the page based on the textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following two tables:

```
Table1
___________
ID
Name
Company
Industry
Rank
Key - guid
```

and

```
Table2
_____________
Key - guid
FieldValue
StartDate
EndDate
```

I am using MVC pattern, not regular web forms. I created 2 separate model classes for each and separate DBContext classes.

Initially when page loads, I display all the data from Table1 on the page. I want to add a textbox at the top of the page and when a user enters a value and hits enter, I want to data in the table on the page to be filtered based on the user-entered value:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Company,Industry, Rank
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Key=Table2.Key
WHERE FieldValue=TextBox1.Text
```

I already have the code to display data from Table1 on the page working fine, but I need help adding the filter based on the value of the textbox. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my code from the view:

```
<input type="text" id="TextBox1" />

<h2>Records</h2>
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Industry</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
        </tr>
 @foreach (ProjectName.Models.Records item in Model)
        {
            <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <td>@item.ID</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Company</td>
                <td>@item.Industry</td>
                <td>@item.Rank</td>

            </tr>
        }
 </table>
```

Here is updated view code:

```
 <div>       
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
    <input type="text" id="TextBox1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
   }

    <h2>Records</h2>
   <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Industry</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (ProjectName.Models.Records item in Model)
    {
        <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <td>@item.ID</td>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.Company</td>
            <td>@item.Industry</td>
            <td>@item.Rank</td>

        </tr>
    }
   </table>
</div>
```

P.S. Dear editors, please please pretty please, stop editing word MVC out of the title - otherwise people assume it is Web Forms pattern and not MVC. SO PLEASE PRETTY PLEASE stop editing it out, you are not helping, only making things difficult. Thank you so much in advance, my appreciation is above and beyond

Comment: There must be a million tutorials on the internet for this, but basically, you need a `<form>` containing your input and button.  The form POSTs to a controller method (it can be the same one that displays the form), and you use the filter parameter in your query to repopulate the ViewModel, pass it to the View and redisplay the page.

Comment: I am using MVC, not Web Forms. Some genius just edited "MVC" out of my post title so everyone got confused

Comment: We know your using MVC because you have tagged it. Do not repeat it in the title

Comment: Stephen Muecke, when you leave it out of the title people still assume it is web forms, so pretty please, let it stay in the title please oh please

Comment: @ElenaDBA, No it should not be in the title. Not only is it stated in the [help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) there is plenty of guidelines in meta explaining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're using MVC, you still need a `<form>` to submit the filter value to a controller method.

This is your textbox within an MVC form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="TextBox1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
}
```

This is rendered as HTML `<form>` tags. Your Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string TextBox1)
{
    // You don't say how you're interacting with the database, 
    // but you need to check the `TextBox1` parameter for null, 
    // and use it in your query if it's not - simplified:
    if(TextBox1 != null)
    {
        // do qry with parameter
    }
    else
    {
       // do qry without parameter
    }
    ...
```

There are several ways to do what I've written above, but this is a simple version that doesn't require modifying your `ViewModel` (mainly because I don't know what it looks like!)

Comment: I tried it and TextBox1 in the Index action always comes up to be null

Comment: Compare the code for the textbox in the version I gave you and the version you've used.

Comment: I just did identical - same result

Comment: It's NOT identical! This is yours: `<input type="text" id="TextBox1" />` this is mine `<input type="text" name="TextBox1" />` see the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [datatables plugin](http://datatables.net/), you have filters with static or server tables.

The very basic example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create something that postback, like an `<as:button>`  and correctly link the event in the code behind, then :

```
using(context db = new context())
{
    List<Table2> var1 = db.Table2.ToList()
    List<Table2> var2 = new List<Table2>()
    foreach(Table2 t in var1)
    {
        if(t.FieldValue == textbox.Text)
        {
            var2.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

and then :

```
 foreach(Table2 t in var2)
  {
      //Bind your things here
  }
```

Sorry if it dosen't help you or if i misunderstood the question.

Comment: As i said, first you have to make an event, are you able to reach code behind with an <asp:button> ? It's important that you reach code behind somehow, anyhow exept page_load()